How can I find the definition of a CSS variable using the browser developer tools?
In a complex website I want to find the place, where a specific CSS variable has been defined.
Assume I look at an HTML tag with some CSS classes like:
<span class="icon-name"></span>

The class definition can be seen in the Styles or Computed tab
.icon-name {
    color: var(--icon-name-color);
}

.icon-name::after {
    background-image: var(--icon-name-image);
}

Now I'd like to find out, where the value of the variables is defined.
The variables are not defined in the same CSS file as the CSS class definition.

it could be also defined on any HTML element

If you're not opposed to using the console and js in your scan, you could store the element as a variable or grab it with a query selector, then use getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("--icon-name-image")

As this was posted some months ago, I presume you are no longer looking for an answer to this, but...
There are two main ways to assign values to custom properties; either through CSS or JS. If it's JavaScript then you could certainly get the value by querying the getComputedStyle of the element, as mentioned by another poster, but you'll need to search the code to find where it is set.
If, however, it's set within the CSS you should be able to find where the value is assigned, and what that value is in context with the selected element, using the developer tools. The layout is slightly different between Firefox and Chrome, but the information is the same.
Open up the Dev Tools...
Firefox: On the [inspector] tab, you should see three panels. On the left select the element you wish to inspect (in the screenshot supplied, I have selected the pseudo-element ::before which is a child of the .inner <div>), the middle panel should display the CSS rules applied to the selected element and it's here you will find where the custom property is set, on the right hand side, swap the tab to [computed] and you will see a list of properties, including the custom one(s) with their associated value.
Chrome: Is very similar just that the [inspector] tab is called [elements] and instead of 3 panels, you are shown two. The left panel is the same as Firefox, and you should select the element you wish to inspect. The right panel has tabs, and switching between the [styles] and [computed] tab, you will get the same information as switching between the middle and right panels in Firefox.
(With Chrome, you will probably need to click the "show all" box on the [computed] tab in order to see all that element's properties, including the custom ones.)
All this is quite hard to visualise so I am providing you with a screenshot of Firefox developer tools, working with two files (html & css). I have uploaded those files to a codepen.
Sample code: https://codepen.io/RickyRiot/pen/LYwWXKg
test.html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>test</title>
  <!-- add in style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
  <!-- some inline css to change the value of the custom property -->
  <style>
   div.inner {
    /* this updates the custom property */
    --text: "inner";
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="outer">
   <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

test.css

/* the original setting of the custom property */
:root {
 --text: "outer";
}

div.inner,
div.outer {
 position: relative;
 border: 1px dotted #888;
 margin: 5rem;
 min-height: 2rem;
}

div.outer::after,
div.inner::after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 /* assigning the value of the custom property to the content rule */
 content: var(--text);
}


Firefox dev tools screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/jQXMPt6.png

In summary, the left panel you need to select the element, the middle panel will show you where the custom property is set, and selecting [computed] on the right panel will give you a list of properties and their values.
You will see that in the middle panel, the :root value is greyed out with the div.inner rule taking precedence. The file, and the line number within that file where the value is assigned, is shown to the upper left of each element's ruleset, clicking on them will swap you to the [style editor] tab which displays more information including highlighting the line (in context) that the attribute assignment was made.
I hope all this makes sense, it's actually a very simple task, but describing it is a longer process.
